# Add formula calculation gravityforms

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I helping a friend of mine to create a calculation formula in gravityforms and Woocommerce.

He whant to add:
number of prints: 1-24, 25-49
And number of prints color: 1, 2

based on the Quantity the prints color have differents prices.

ex:
prints 1-24, color 1 = 22,50 Skr
Prints 25-49, color 2 = 17,50 Skr

in my form now i have, product name, number of prints ( where i type the number of prints ), number of prints color ( dropdown ), And total.

But i don´t now how i add the calculation formula.

Hope some one can help us.

Answer (score 0):

I try not to post links to my products here unless I can provide a free alternative as well... but in this case, I do not know of a simple or free way to accomplish this without the use of my [GP Conditional Pricing](http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-conditional-pricing/) add-on for Gravity Forms. It supports tiered pricing (also known as bulk discounts) as you've described here. You'll need a copy of [Gravity Perks](http://gravityperks.com) to download this add-on.